# Alternative to Yield in Python

Tags: python, yield

Is there an alternative (even if longer) method of writing the `yield` part of this code? I'm not very familiar with the function and would rather keep it simple.

```
for i in range(0, len(lstInput) - intCount + 1):
    if intCount == 1:
        yield [lstInput[i]]
    else:
        current = lstInput[i]
        remainder = lstInput[i+1:]
        for rest in yieldLotto(remainder, intCount - 1):
            yield [current] + rest
```

Comment: u can use a list and append to that

Comment: [How about instead you learn what `yield` does?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained)

Comment: Seriously, though, `yield` is not complex.  Just take the 20 minutes to learn it completely and you'll never worry about it again. @jwodder's SO link is perfect and even has some links to slideshows if I remember correctly.  (It's how I learned yield).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alternative is to either embed the loops into your calling program, or to change it to return a list.  This means everything will be going into memory, though.

```
def foo():
    return_list = []
    for i in range(0, len(lstInput) - intCount + 1):
        if intCount == 1:
            return_list.append([lstInput[i]])
        else:
            current = lstInput[i]
            remainder = lstInput[i+1:]
            for rest in yieldLotto(remainder, intCount - 1):
                return_list.append([current] + rest)
    return return_list
```

Honestly though, I think yield is better and it's an important feature of Python.  I suggest learning it.